# DynamoDB Query to get all rows between two string prefixes

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm storing attendance data per school/class/section/subject as follows

```
Partition_key => schoolID + classID + sectionID + subjectID
RangeKey => ts + studentID
```

My requirement is to search for all the attendance records for a given partition key between timestamp TS1 and TS2.

Essentially, I'd need to find all the range keys starting with TS1 and ending with TS2 + infinity. Is there any way to perform such a query in DynamoDB?

Comment: You have all the  4 values of partition keys?

Comment: @notionquest: I think I need a BETWEEN comparator on the range key. EDIT : Essentially, I need to do RangeKEY BETWEEN (TS1, TS2). Since rangekey is a string, between gives me all records between timestamp TS1 and TS2. Do you think there's any problem?

Comment: Yes, if you have the partition key.

Comment: comparing string and number is different. between("1", "10") is different from between(1, 10)

Comment: However, timestamp string in ISO 8601 format is acceptable, but you are appending timestamp with studentID.